# ページを別ファイル化した時のons-templateについて

Tags: onsen-ui

index.htmlからタップによってpage1.html（別ファイル）にnavigator.pushPage()で遷移した場合
pgae1.htmlにはons-templateを記述は可能なのでしょうか？

使い方が正しいか分かりませんが、page1.htmlにons-page（初期表示される）を記述して、それとは別にons-templateを使いたい感じです。
このように別ファイル化した場合、ons-templateではなく、同じく別ファイル化しないとダメなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[複数のhtmlファイルとons-templateを併用するとうまく動かない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9368/)

こちらの質問に回答がありますが、別ファイルの`ons-template`を使用するには事前に`ng-include`しておく必要があるようです。

`<ng-include src="'page1.html'"></ng-include>`

ただ、今回のように`index.html`の`ons-navigator`に設定する場合はこれだけだとうまく動かないようです（おそらく`page1.html`の読み込みが終わらない。やり方がまずいだけかもしれませんが・・・）。

**page1.html** ※これは下記A, B, Cで共通

```
<ons-template id="sub-page1">
  <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Sub Page 1</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div style="text-align: center">
          <h1>Sub Page 1</h1>
          <ons-button onclick="navi.pushPage('sub-page2')">
            Push Page
          </ons-button>  
      </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="sub-page2">
  <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
          <div class="center">Sub Page 2</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div style="text-align: center">
          <h1>Sub Page 2</h1>
          <ons-button onclick="navi.popPage()">
            Pop Page
          </ons-button>  
      </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

**index.html**

A. これはうまく動かない

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ～ 中略 ～
    <script>
      ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-include src="'page1.html'"></ng-include>
    <ons-navigator var="navi" page="sub-page1">
    </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

B. これはうまく動いた（と思う）※たまに動かない

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ～ 中略 ～
    <script>
    　ons.bootstrap();
      ons.ready(function() {
        // page1.html内のページを設定
        navi.resetToPage('sub-page1');
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-include src="'page1.html'"></ng-include>
    // とりあえずダミーを設定
    <ons-navigator var="navi" page="dummy">
    </ons-navigator>
    <ons-template id="dummy">
      // ダミーページ
    </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

C. これが一番成功率が高い気がする ※たまに動かない

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ～ 中略 ～
    <script>
    　ons.bootstrap();
      ons.ready(function() {
        // 500ミリ秒待ってからpage1.html内のページを設定
        setTimeout(function() {
          navi.resetToPage('sub-page1');
        }, 500);
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-include src="'page1.html'"></ng-include>
    <ons-navigator var="navi">
    </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

せっかく試したので B も記載していますが、C の方がお手軽な気はします。

- C の待ち時間を調整する
- 準備ができたら呼ばれるイベントを探す

等で「たまに動かない」は解消できるかもしれません。

Comment: お礼が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
コードまで記載して頂いき大変ありがとうございます。

提示していただいたコードはons-navigatorのpage属性なので
ボタンを押した時のpushPageでも同じような挙動なのか試してみたいと思います。